# sending json to d3js graph

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, d3.js

I have a series of stored `JSON objects`(below) being sent out my `html` page via `angular`, 
the issue I have is getting the information from angular out to my `d3.js` graph.(i think i need to convert them from `JSON` to normal values
for my x axis data to be graphed)

```
 { __v: 0, temp: 328, _id: 56e9417d6a8a307819c3e598 },
 { __v: 0, temp: 328, _id: 56e9417d6a8a307819c3e599 },
 { __v: 0, temp: 328, _id: 56e9417d6a8a307819c3e600 },
 { __v: 0, temp: 328, _id: 56e941826a8a307819c3e59a }
```

the below `$http` request received the data from `app.js`.
  the `y axis` is sales(value of objects) and the `x axis` is hour(amount of entries from database to display)

```
   $http.get('/solution-two/data3').success(function (data) {
            var hour=$scope.salesData3.length+1;
            var sales= data;
            $scope.salesData3.push({hour: hour, sales:sales});
        });
```

I have the array starting off with an array which gets the info sent in to the http request

```
 $scope.salesData3=[
 {hour: 1,sales: 280}];
```

`salesData3` is the name of my `d3.js` graph, so in summary i think i need to defice my length of hour variable with the length of database entries 
and sales variable needs to accept the `JSON` objects from the database, would i be correct?

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question clearly, you are looking for the structure in which you can send the data in JSON to D3 ?

If you are plotting a line graph of sales vs hour, then you do not need to check for the length of the hour. Instead D3 has methods to detect the time format, which can be used to assign it to the X-Axis.

```
x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
y = d3.time.scale().range([height, 0]);
// Set the X axis domain with time
y.domain(d3.extent(salesData3, function (d) {
            return d.sales;
        }));
valueLine = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.hour);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.sales);
            });
svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "CLASS_NAME")
        .attr("id", curveId)
        .attr("d", valueLine(salesData3));
```

This link has an example on how you can use a JSON array and pass it as a data to the x and y axis https://www.dashingd3js.com/using-json-to-simplify-code

Nice link which explains the task of formatting the time http://www.d3noob.org/2012/12/formatting-date-time-on-d3js-graph.html & http://jsfiddle.net/robdodson/KWRxW/

Comment: Thanks for the comment and info that is great stuff .I am using the graph for other live info, so I was hoping to change the json to var values within angular controller. As in, pull the values out of json array and push in to sales var to be then graphed on d3.

Comment: When D3 supports the array data structure natively, IMHO it would be appropriate to pass on an array rather than iterating through the array ("pull the values out of json array") and then reuse the value to build the graph.